# .NET hosting in china: IIS 7 + MSSQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, umbraco, windows-server-2008-r2

A client of ours need hosting for a Chinese website - in china.

We have trouble finding a Chinese web hosting provider that use IIS 7 and MSSQL 2008 R2

It's for an Umbraco website.

The client has local presence, so we don't need certificates from cnnic.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably looking for hosting companies on Hong Kong if that's an option to you, I'm sure there are plenty.

It might be worth giving these guys a call http://www.hktechnology.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try a search on Baidu using Google-translate.

use the following Chinese 'dialect': Chinese-simplified (Han).

Answer (score 0):

Reply a bit too late but I wanted to share anyway:

http://www.temasektech.com/china_vps.html

Expensive, but doesn't require ICP license.